# How to pass data using static properties in a class

Tags: swift, swift3

1) I would like to know if it is ok to pass data using static properties in a class.

for example: I create a class using swift class instead of Obj-C class:

Store this class in Model folder

```
class Player {

    static var playerName: String =""
    static var score: Int = 0
    static var Team: String =""
}
```

in VC1.

I set

```
Player.playerName ="Alexander"
```

in VC2:
I access it :

```
var strPlayerInAction = Player.playerName
```

2) How to declare a static Class ?

```
static class Player{


}
```

This way, I can pass many data in a flexible ways. But will this cause any problem ?

Comment: There are no "static classes". It is okey to use static properties if the properties are actually shared by all instances of your class. That's not the case here.

Comment: Just create a static property for a shared instance of your class. `static var sharedInstance = Player()`

Comment: And pass around `Player.sharedInstance.whatever`

Comment: @ Leo Dabus, can u show me how it works. Mainly, this Class is like a storage that I can access in different ViewControllers to share and pass data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using a struct.

```
struct Players {
    static var playerName = "name"
}
```